# How to return Video from my Custom Camera to Messenger

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Manifest(here my CameraApp can be called by another(ex. Telegram) app using intent):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

I want to return recorded Video (Uri or File) by EXTRA_OUTPUT??? to messenger. I think from messenger its called something like this: (ex. for photo)

```
f = new File(str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
startActivityForResult(new Intent(
    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(
    MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)),
    Take_Photo);
System.err.println("f  " + f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private fun finishWithResult() {
        val sendVideoIntent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        sendVideoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(File(mVideoFileName)))
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, sendVideoIntent)
        sendBroadcast(sendVideoIntent)
        //TODO finish()
    }
```

Comment: That's pretty, but how can I detect, if my activity was called by another app(then call finish()), otherwise I want to continue